# How to check updates of a website automatically regularly?

Tags: android, ubuntu, web, rss

I want to know is there any way to check updates of a website regularly?

I am a student. My exam schedules comes in university [web site](http://exams.keralauniversity.ac.in/Login/stud_session_login.php) .I don't wanna miss that. So is there any way I can check this details automatically? I am using android and Ubuntu. Please help me. I don't think that the website have rss feed.

Answer (score 1):

The website http://changemon.com/ is one of many website trackers that will send you an email when a website element is changed.

If you prefer a more diy solution, there is always use a scraping tool such as scrapy (python) http://scrapy.org/ and create your own project.